CORS error after deployment of backend on vercel
when i run my app before deployment then i faced CORS error i read docs and fixed that one now i hosted my backend on vercel now again i am facing the same issue the error is same as
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://book-store-backend-eight-fawn.vercel.app/books' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.Understand this error
Home.jsx:25 AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
Home.jsx:19
GET https://book-store-backend-eight-fawn.vercel.app/books net::ERR_FAILED 404 (Not Found)
// Middleware for handling CORS POLICY
app.use(cors({
origin : "*"
}));
i passed middleware cors but still i am facing the same issue

Can you try it by not specifying any origin route? i.e. app.use(cors());
